# Java - Interactive map over highest mountains in Europe

Tags: java

I am making an interactive map over the highest mountains in each country in Europe. My aim is to make it possible to click on the country and then get all the information and possibly a picture of the highest mountain in that country. My current code is quite dirty and I am therefore looking for suggestions here. I know it would be easier to do it in another language, but my goal is to do it in Java. I have used a SWT window and uploaded the map into a label. Does anyone have a suggestion for a better way to upload the image?

Thanks.

```
    package mtnMapEur;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.FormToolkit;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;

public class map {

    protected Shell shell;
    private final FormToolkit formToolkit = new FormToolkit(Display.getDefault());
    private Text txtMeters;
    private Text txtCountryNorway;
    private Text txtHighestMountainGaldhpiggen;
    private Button btnTest;
    private Label label;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            map window = new map();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }




public void list(){



    }   /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     */
    protected void createContents() {
        shell = new Shell();
        shell.setMinimumSize(new Point(2400, 2284));
        shell.setSize(515, 479);
        shell.setText("SWT Application");
        shell.setMaximized(true);


        Label lblNewLabel = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        lblNewLabel.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("/Users/Hadle/Downloads/Optimized-mapEur.gif"));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, -24, 1400, 900);



        btnTest = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        btnTest.setBounds(615, 198, 94, 194);
        formToolkit.adapt(btnTest, true, true);
        btnTest.setText("Test");

        label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        label.setBounds(593, 10, 59, 14);
        formToolkit.adapt(label, true, true);
        label.setText("New Label");


        btnTest.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

                    txtCountryNorway = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
                    txtCountryNorway.setText("Country: Norway");
                    txtCountryNorway.setBounds(22, 112, 204, 30);
                    formToolkit.adapt(txtCountryNorway, true, true);

                    txtHighestMountainGaldhpiggen = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
                    txtHighestMountainGaldhpiggen.setText("Highest Mountain: Galdhøpiggen");
                    txtHighestMountainGaldhpiggen.setBounds(22, 148, 204, 30);
                    formToolkit.adapt(txtHighestMountainGaldhpiggen, true, true);

                    txtMeters = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
                    txtMeters.setText("Meters above sea level: 24xx");
                    txtMeters.setBounds(22, 184, 204, 30);
                    formToolkit.adapt(txtMeters, true, true);
            }





    });
}   
}
```

Comment: Is the code working? Review/best practice questions are better placed in the [Code Review Stack Exchange site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This code is working for me but does not include the SWTResourceManager, so will not work for you. I added it so you can get a overview.